# Rails 3.2.8 attr_accessor not seemingly working with form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got a few problems with an attr_accessor when using a form_tag in one my views.

```
<%= form_tag set_location_locations_path, :method => "post" do %>
  <%= collection_select(:location, :location_id, Location.all, :id, :location_name) %>
  <%= submit_tag "Go" %>
<% end %>
```

And in my location model I have this:

```
 attr_accessor :location, :location_id
```

And I've also tried attr_writer for good measure.

When I submit the form, I can see this in my console:

```
  ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `location_id' for "1":String):
```

And the post looks like this:

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"oY+jSCV9Mz9iVJnJItADnHdpGhct5DhKpQ+w6JUvgNQ=", "location"=>{"location_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Go"}
```

I can't figure out why this doesn't work? Previously I've used attr_accessor without problems. Is there something I'm missing?

---- EDIT ----

Controller (not much there)

```
def set_location
  @location = params[:location][:location_id]      
end
```

View not much here either:

```
 = @location
```

Comment: When you submit your form the parameters are going as expected so where are you actually seeing the error??

Comment: The point of the form is to set some session params. For testing purposes I'm just submitting to set_location (in locations controller). And I'm trying to see the params with: @location = params[:location][:location_id]

Comment: What does `set_location` look like? Do you get the template error before or after the parameters in your log?

Comment: The parameters are right. We need to see the controller code for your action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your collection_select is expecting a Location instance with a method location_id. You're assigning `'1'` to your @location variable so it tries `'1'.location_id` and complains. Change your set_location method to something like:

```
def set_location
  @location = Location.new(params[:location])
end
```

Comment: Ok. That's got it. Thanks. Is it also possible to grab the location id so the select dropdown shows the correct location?